# NullPointerException encountered when adding objects to ArrayDeque

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, arraydeque

The class is intended to hold a stack of room numbers (i.e. the rooms in which a hotel guest has stayed in) and allow retrieval of the last room stayed (LIFO).

For now, I just want to add an item but doesn't seem to work. I could use a stack for this, but I am experimenting with ArrayDeque (as it's supposed to be more flexible?).

Anyway, when executing the addRoom() method providing an integer as a parameter, the ArrayDeque throws a NullPointerException on line 14 where I use the **addFirst()** or **add()** method of ArrayDeque.

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque; 

public class RoomNumbers
{
    private ArrayDeque<Integer> roomNumbers;

    public RoomNumbers()
    {
        ArrayDeque<Integer> roomNumbers = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
    }

    public void addRoom(int roomNumber)
    {
       roomNumbers.addFirst(roomNumber);
    }
}
```

I don't understand how it can complain that the integer is null when I explicitly provide an integer value.  Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class RoomNumbers {
        private ArrayDeque<Integer> roomNumbers;

        public RoomNumbers()
        {
           roomNumbers = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
        }

        public void addRoom(int roomNumber)
        {
            roomNumbers.addFirst(roomNumber);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RoomNumbers roomNumbers = new RoomNumbers();
        roomNumbers.addRoom(1);
    }
}
```

[the difference between local and global variables in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858226/local-vs-global-variables-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor RoomHistory doesn't match with your class RoomNumbers, and thus roomNumbers instance has not been initialized, leads to NullPointerException being thrown.

And don't redeclare roomNumbers in the constructor.

Comment: Duc, thank you for your response. 

Still experiencing the same error on the same line, after matching constructor with class name.